# Jmeter JSONAssertion Failure Message

Tags: json, performance, jmeter, httpresponse, assertion

```
while performing the JSON Assertion using Jmeter , i get the following error.
```

> Expected to find object with property $['id'] in path $["body"] but
>   found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'.
>       This is not a json object according to the JSON Provider.'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.

```
please let me know what is the issue ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that your [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query doesn't match anything in the response data.

For example if you have JSON like:

```
{
  "body": [
    {
      "id": 28,
      "Title": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "id": 56,
      "Title": "USA"
    },
    {
      "id": 89,
      "Title": "England"
    }
  ]
}
```

And you configure [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) like:

[image]

It will fail because the JSON Path query matches > 1 element:

[image]

In order to test i.e. `28` value you need to amend your JSON Path query to point to the first entry in the `body` [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)

```
$.body[0].id
```

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Plugin in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-json-plugin-in-jmeter/)